# Which height does a font-size in pixels refer to?

Tags: css, fonts, pixel

In many programs or systems you can specify a font-size by pixel height. (Photoshop, CSS, etc.)

What does this refer to exactly? Is it the height from the descender to the ascender? From the baseline to the cap height? I haven't been able to find out whether there's a standard for it, or if each application handles it differently.

// EDIT

I just realized this isn't really the right place to be asking this. Is there a way to remove this question?

Comment: You should see a delete button below the post next to "share" and "edit".

Comment: As a question about CSS specifically, I think this is on-topic, though a duplicate – the same question has been asked several times in different forms. Unfortunately, most answers (including accepted answers) are more or less wrong, and it is difficult to say which variant is the question that should be improved.

Answer (score 4):

Well the answer is 'descender to the ascender' (round about), BUT every font works different and has a different rendering in Programms, Browsers etc. So if you are using a font wich in not 'normal', but a little smaller than normal, it is actually smaller than the pixel yu give it with font-size. On the other hand there are.

If you look at my Image (enlarged in Photoshop) this is Arial at font-size:18px; but from the bottom to the top its 17px. So its not 100% Accurate and can change by different fonts and different platforms & Programms.

[image]

Comment: “From lowest descender to highest ascender” is just a coarse rule of thumb, and fonts differ from it in either direction.